# Postfix with Docker: Error connecting to SMTP - 454 4.7.1: Relay access denied

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, docker, configuration

So I have the following Setup

Ubuntu 16.04 Server with postfix installed, running BigBlueButton

On that, I have a docker container with Greenlight which is basicly the frontend of BigBlueButton

This Docker Container has the IP 172.18.0.3 (which I added to my networks at the postfix config file)

When I run

```
docker run --rm --env-file .env bigbluebutton/greenlight:v2 bundle exec rake conf:check
```

to check if the config and mail is working, I get the following output:

```
Checking environment: Passed
Checking Connection: Passed
Checking Secret: Passed
Checking SMTP connection: Failed
Error connecting to SMTP - 454 4.7.1 <dl@niteo.agency>: Relay access denied
```

My Greenlight(Docker) SMTP Config in .env File:

```
SMTP_SERVER=mydomain.example.com
SMTP_PORT=25
SMTP_DOMAIN=mydomain.example.com
#SMTP_USERNAME=
#SMTP_PASSWORD=
#SMTP_AUTH=
SMTP_STARTTLS_AUTO=true

# Specify the email address that all mail is sent from
SMTP_SENDER=no-reply@mydomain.example.com

# Specify the recipient for test emails (needed for providers like Microsoft, who are very
# strict about RFC 2606)
SMTP_TEST_RECIPIENT=my@testemail.com
```

My postfix main.cf File:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

mydomain = mydomain.example.com
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, $mydomain, $myhostname
relayhost =
mynetworks = localhost, 127.0.0.1, 172.18.0.2, 172.18.0.3
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_domains=mydomain.example.com
relay_domains = $mydestination
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
```

I have tried various changes to mynetworks setting, including setting it to 0.0.0.0 which to my knowledge should allow anyone to send mails - but it still didn't work.

EDIT:

This is my postfix log:

```
connect from unknown[172.17.0.2]
Nov 17 13:42:58 webinar postfix/smtpd[5604]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[172.17.0.2]: 454 4.7.1 <my@testemail.com>: Relay access denied; from=$ from=<no-reply@mydomain.example.com> to=<my@testemail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mydomain.example.com>

Nov 17 13:42:58 webinar postfix/smtpd[5604]: disconnect from unknown[172.17.0.2] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/6
```

Comment: Check the postfix logs.

Comment: I added the postfix log @MichaelHampton

Comment: You could try to "comma-separate" the values of "smtpd_relay_restrictions".
What about activation the loglevel "DEBUG" for Postfix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that you got the IP addresses right? According to your postfix log, the sender is 172.17.0.2, not 172.18.0.3.

Could you add 172.17.0.2 to `mynetworks` and try again?

Comment: that actually worked - not sure how i could miss that! thank you so much! do you have any idea why its not using the docker container ip?

Comment: Glad I could help. Regarding the IP address: idk how you found the IP address in the first place. What I would do is find the docker network the container is attached to and issue an `docker network inspect whatever_the_networks_name`. This shows all containers and their respective IP addresses. If you still can't figure out what's wrong, just open another question around here.

Comment: I found that with docker inspect container_name and it gave me that address in the config - guess the network is what I have to check